# sorting initialiser lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing the codeacedemy python course and i wondered why snippet 1 works but snippet 2 doesn't

snippet 1

```
 inventory['pocket'] = ['seashell','strange berry','lint']
 inventory['pocket'].sort()
```

snippet 2

```
inventory['pocket'] = ['seashell','strange berry','lint'].sort()
```

I would just expect snippet 2 to sort the list before assigning it to the pocket instead it sets pocket to 'None'.

Comment: `[...].sort()` returns `None`. If you store the return value of `[...].sort()`, you are storing `None`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` method works in-place. The list you call it on is sorted, and then the `sort` method returns `None`. If all you want is the sorted list, use the `sorted` built-in function.

```
inventory['pocket'] = sorted(['seashell','strange berry','lint'])
```

Comment: ok it was stuff like this that confused me, a,b = b,a+b.
so i was expecting everything to the right to be calculated and resolved before assigning to the left. 
so list created, list sorted, list assigned.

Comment: @WendyLisaGibbons: Everything on the right is calculated before assigning to the targets on the left, but it goes "list created, list sorted, *return value of the `sort` call assigned*", not "list assigned".